# Hell, as they say

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus

**What does the puzzle below represent, and what four-letter word corresponds to the missing image?**

---

[image: Eleven/twelve images with one letter attached to each, blank box with question mark]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The puzzle represents

> the **[Twelve Olympians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Olympians)**

Each image

> contains a symbol representing one of the Greek gods/goddesses along with the first letter of his or her name.

From left to right

> **Demeter**, goddess of harvest
>  **Poseidon**, god of the sea
>  **Athena**, goddess of war
>  **Aphrodite**, goddess of beauty
>  **Hephaestus**, god of blacksmiths
>  **Hera**, goddess of marriage
>  **Apollo**, god of the sun
>  **Hestia**, goddess of the family / **Dionysus**, god of wine, considered by various authors to be one of the Twelve Olympians
>  **Hermes**, the messenger god
>  **Ares**, god of war
>  **Artemis**, goddess of the moon

The missing image and four letter word would then be

> **Zeus**, King of the gods of Mount Olympus!

@Stiv points out that the title

> is a reference to **Hellas**, Latinization of **Ἑλλάς**, the Ancient Greek word for Greece.

Comment: The title is a reference to rot13(URYYNF, orvat gur Terrx jbeq sbe Terrpr, ubzr bs gurfr cnegvphyne tbqf)

Comment: All good. Nice job!